# Reading of megohm during ground check

Tags: resistance, ground, multimeter, ohmmeter

During the check of pins on connector with a multi-meter, one of the pins that goes through the relay to provide ground signal, I am getting 8MOhm (8 megohm). I should not be getting anything on that pin as the relay should be de-energized. How should I interpret this reading? I was under the assumption since the readout in megohms should it be ignored as a possible issue?

[image: readout of the pin]

Comment: Without more information about the circuit in question it is pretty difficult to give a specific answer. But, you have an open circuit where you expected continuity so look for a bad connection.

Comment: Schematic required with indication of where you are taking the measurement. You can add one in using the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar. Double-click a component to edit its properties. 'R' = rotate, 'H' = horizontal flip. 'V' = vertical flip. 

Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar and "Save and Insert" on the editor an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please edit your show a schematic. The schematic tool here is easy to use. The better the quality of question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a warm welcome.

Answer (score 0):

“...thru the relay... ,...”de-energized” suggest you believe the NO (normally open) contact should present an open circuit. If you are not reading across the relay’s NO contact you might be reading a path you don’t expect.